# Programming a plug and play device

Tags: plugins, plug-and-play

Does anyone know how to go about programming a chip in order to make it plug and play? i.e how to include the PNPID in the hardware etc? The external device shall be interacting via the USB port.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Much really depends on the OS you're plugging the device into.

From the hardware device perspective, these links might help:

- http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml
- http://www.usb.org/developers/
- http://www.cesko.host.sk/IgorPlugUSB/IgorPlug-USB%20%28AVR%29_eng.htm